# Python Not being able to restart program after input of wishing to continue

Tags: python

I am trying to restart the program to start over if I press Yes if I wish to continue but after quite a bit of reading could not figure out a solution. I am trying to restart the funciton buth with no success. When I press Y to continue it does completely wrong calculations not bringing me back to start all over. Any help would be appreciated.

```
oo_large_value = 100000
dimes = -1
quarters = -1
nickels = -1
pennies = 0
continue_execution = 'Y'

#Continue Until User doesn't want to exit
while continue_execution == 'Y':
    print("Please enter the number of coins:")

    #input quarters
    while quarters < 0 or quarters >= too_large_value:
        try:
            quarters = int(input("# of quarters:"))
            #if user entered negative value, give error
            if quarters < 0:
                print("Please Enter a positive Value:")
            #if user entered too large value, give error
            elif quarters >= too_large_value:
                print("Entered Value is too large.\nPlease Enter between 0 and 99999:")
        #if user didn't enter an integer,throw exception
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Please Enter Integer value only:")
    quarters=quarters*25

    while dimes < 0 or dimes >= too_large_value:
        try:
            dimes = int(input("# of dimes:"))
            # if user entered negative value, give error
            if dimes < 0:
                print("Please Enter a positive Value:")
            # if user entered too large value, give error
            elif dimes >= too_large_value:
                print("Entered Value is too large.\nPlease Enter between 0 and 99999:")
        # if user didn't enter an integer,throw exception
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Please Enter Integer value only:")
    dimes=dimes*10
    while nickels < 0 or nickels >= too_large_value:
        try:
            nickels = int(input("# of nickels:"))
            # if user entered negative value, give error
            if nickels < 0:
                print("Please Enter a positive Value:")
            # if user entered too large value, give error
            elif nickels >= too_large_value:
                print("Entered Value is too large.\nPlease Enter between 0 and 99999:")
        # if user didn't enter an integer,throw exception
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Please Enter Integer value only:")
    nickels=nickels*5

    #calculate pennies
    pennies = quarters + dimes + nickels

    #print total pennies
    print(f'The total is {pennies} pennies')

    #Ask if user wants to  Continue or not
    print("Do You want to Enter another value?")
    continue_execution = input("Y for Yes and N for N:")

    #makes sure user enters only 'Y' or 'N'
    while continue_execution != 'Y' and continue_execution != 'N':
        print("Invalid Choice\nPlease Enter again")
        continue_execution = input("Y for Yes and N for N: ")

print("Thank you for doing business with us!")
```

Comment: Each run of your outer `while` loop is a brand new start.  So, move all of your initialization (`dimes = -1`, etc) INSIDE the while loop.

Comment: You need to re-initialize all the variables like `quarters`, `dimes`, etc. when the loop restarts. Put all those variable assignments after `while continue_execution == 'Y':`